# Why do links in question and answer work differently then links in comments?

Tags: discussion, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

Currently when linking to other question, one might use just the `[link](http://example.com)`. This works great in questions, answers and comments. So far so good. Now when mentioning link in a question or answer, there is additional feature that this link is automatically resolved to the referenced question title (at least on same SE site). For some reason this feature is missing when mentioning links in a comments. Is there some intent behind this? If not, can this be enabled?

I realize that in most of the cases, the link someone wants to mention in comments is a duplicate, in which case it is done automatically through the flagging feature. But this is not always the case, sometimes one just wants to refer other related question, not a duplicate. Having this feature enabled the comments would shorten the typing and message length if just link would suffice.

This is probably something that must have been discussed already, but I haven't found anything much except things like https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478, which basically just says it cannot be done... Also this question might be more for some "meta-meta", feel free to redirect me to correct page.

Comment: This feature request seems related: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394). (Score 133, status-declined.)

Comment: BTW it's kind of nice irony that you mention that links are automatically expanded to titles in posts - but already your post shows that this is not always reliable. (At least [in the original revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/28598/1) the link to [Links in comments](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2478) at Software Engineering Meta is shown as bare url.) For quite a long time I use `[text](url)` format also in posts - after seeing many situations where it did not work, maybe it's better to stay on the safe side.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It seems it is related to the link refering to a different SE site, then it does not resolve it. Anyway thanks for the link, I totally agree with points there, the link could be resolved into the `[text](url)` when you send the comment first time, similarly as it it with duplicate questions... I mean it works reliably there so... It's a bit shame there is no will to make such changes, but I guess that is just the way it is.

Comment: On the other hand, comments have magic links like `[edit]`, `[tour]`, `[main]`: [edit] [tour] [main] which don't work in posts.